# F# function call dependency graphs

Tags: f#, metaprogramming

We have an application in F# with a deep function call dependency graph. It performs financial calculations in a hierarchical fashion.

How could we extract the graph of dependency calls? We are not interested in the full AST, just the dependency between modules/functions.

The purpose is to have a simplified version of the code which can be used in conversations with domain experts.

Comment: Yes, they do. But their current specifications are incredibly awkward and complex. The domain can be explained in simpler ways as we have prototyped in some POCs. So the plan is to devise a better model with the domain experts (who are not, by the way, model designing experts).

Comment: If you have control over the source, and don't mind refactoring, you could do what Prismatic did and write wrappers around the functions so that you can extract the graph (http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Graph-Clojure-Prismatic). In F#, I guess you could use computation expressions for this (or just special "decorator" functions).

Comment: A similar approach to Prismatic/Schema is exactly what I need (although this particular question was narrowed and correcly answered within its scope). I'm wondering which would be the most fsharpest way to do it (further questions for sure).
In essence, Prismatic/Schema allow to define a declarative specification of input-outputs of functions and relate them to implementations through special keyword. And the use a simple map so a graph can be built in 5 LOC and really interesting stuff can be made easily (mocking, partial graph building, testing, etc.).

Comment: I have asked for clues here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24932086/specify-function-composition-through-declarative-maps-in-f

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scott Wlaschin has done similar things in his ['Cycles and modularity in the wild'](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/cycles-and-modularity-in-the-wild/) article. [His approach](https://gist.github.com/swlaschin/5742974) uses Mono.Cecil as a metadata reader and spit out dependency graphs in SVG. A recent article, ['Analysis of Roslyn vs. the F# compiler'](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/roslyn-vs-fsharp-compiler/) uses [the same method](https://gist.github.com/swlaschin/10558434#file-typedependencyanalysis_rosyln-fsx).

You might be able to modify these scripts for your purpose. The downside is that the approach isn't very precise; some F#-specific information might be lost when the code is compiled down to IL.

Another approach is to use [FSharp.Compiler.Service](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Compiler.Service) as a metadata reader; its advantage is flexibility, however, it might take some time to get used to FSharp.Compiler.Service API. You could get started by traversing the whole hierarchy starting from an assembly signature. Here is a [relevant example](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Compiler.Service/blob/master/docs/content/project.fsx#L127-L1380) and [documentation](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/project.html).

In the same spirit, if functions are annotated with ReflectedDefinitionAttribute, then Reflection, Quotations and Pattern modules can be used to retrieve the dependency graph. This approach is explained and detailed in [FSharp Journal](http://fsharpnews.blogspot.com.es/2014/03/call-graph-visualizer.html).