# Specify function composition through declarative maps in F#

Tags: clojure, f#, metaprogramming, function-composition

The [Clojure Prismatic/Plumbing library](https://github.com/Prismatic/plumbing) can be used in order to provide a declarative and explicit definition of an application or module functions' graph.

In short, it provides a means to specify each function as a node with a label, which is also the output label, the labeled inputs, and an implementation. It uses a custom keyword (fkn) defined in a macro for this purpose.

We have to develop a module in F# which performs relatively complex calculations in a hierarchical fashion that could benefit from Prismatic features, namely:

- A graph can be built easily from function map, just taking inputs as dependencies. This graph can be analyzed, checked and visualized with very little code. Also subgraphs could be written providing further flexibility (valuable in our domain).
- Function execution can be monitored. Not only performance but values in and out of each function.
- Testing and Mocking of the system is really easy.

More on these and other features [on github](https://github.com/Prismatic/plumbing/blob/master/test/plumbing/graph_examples_test.cljx) and [infoq presentation](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Graph-Clojure-Prismatic):

What would be the fsharpest way to program this declarative definition of functions in a map in order to get these features?

Comment: This library appears to depend heavily on dynamic typing and metaprogramming, two things which F# supports only meagerly. This probably explains the silence on this question.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This approach that can be made with ease in Clojure , Javascript or Python, needs a decent amount of reflection in F#. Anyway I expected a bit more of hints from F# experts. I hope the requested features can be made with a combination of quotations and computation expressions.

Comment: If [this "planned" UserVoice request](http://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/5975797-allow-implicit-quotation-of-expressions-used-as-a) makes it into F# 4.0 such a library might become more feasible. But, for now, it would be quite difficult, I think.

Comment: @Daniel the other issue is probably that this question really should have been closed since its not really a good fit for SO.  Its more of a research topic than a q/a style question.

Comment: @mydogisbox 3 features are requested, being the most important build a map of functions. With sufficent F# expertise I think it could be answered if this is feasible using language features or not. I'm not requesting research in algorithms or solving unsolved problems.

Comment: @jruizaranguren "Design my program for me" is decidedly outside of the scope of SO no matter how you phrase it.

Comment: @mydogisbox I can see your point, but can't accept your arguments (it is not R+D nor design). My problem is researched, modelled, and the solution designed. We have POCs in Clojure and Javascript. Anyway if F# experts tell me this question is not answerable, I delete it, no problem for that.

Comment: @Vesa.A.J.K I'm glad to here that there are several choices. I'm aware the question is in the SO frontier, but if several choices exist, it confirms me that it is not so off-topic. Thank you for the Applicative functors ntoe.